# ROS2 foxy ros1_bridge

Tags: ros2, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use ROS2 Foxy to spawn a Turtlebot in Gazebo which is in ROS1.

Inside ROS1 when I do `rosservice list`, I see the following

```
/gazebo/apply_body_wrench
/gazebo/apply_joint_effort
/gazebo/clear_body_wrenches
/gazebo/clear_joint_forces
/gazebo/delete_light
/gazebo/delete_model
/gazebo/get_joint_properties
/gazebo/get_light_properties
/gazebo/get_link_properties
/gazebo/get_link_state
/gazebo/get_loggers
/gazebo/get_model_properties
/gazebo/get_model_state
/gazebo/get_physics_properties
/gazebo/get_world_properties
/gazebo/pause_physics
/gazebo/reset_simulation
/gazebo/reset_world
/gazebo/set_joint_properties
/gazebo/set_light_properties
/gazebo/set_link_properties
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_logger_level
/gazebo/set_model_configuration
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gazebo/set_parameters
/gazebo/set_physics_properties
/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model
/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
/gazebo/unpause_physics
/gazebo_gui/get_loggers
/gazebo_gui/set_logger_level
/gazebo_gui/set_parameters
/master_discovery/get_loggers
/master_discovery/list_masters
/master_discovery/refresh
/master_discovery/set_logger_level
/master_sync/get_loggers
/master_sync/get_sync_info
/master_sync/set_logger_level
/param_sync/get_loggers
/param_sync/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
```

However when I run `ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --bridge-all-topics` I see the following

```
Created 2 to 1 bridge for service /gazebo/pause_physics
Created 2 to 1 bridge for service /gazebo/reset_simulation
Created 2 to 1 bridge for service /gazebo/reset_world
Created 2 to 1 bridge for service /gazebo/unpause_physics
Created 2 to 1 bridge for service /master_discovery/refresh
created 1to2 bridge for topic '/rosout' with ROS 1 type 'rosgraph_msgs/Log' and ROS 2 type 'rcl_interfaces/msg/Log'
created 2to1 bridge for topic '/rosout' with ROS 2 type 'rcl_interfaces/msg/Log' and ROS 1 type 'rosgraph_msgs/Log'
[INFO] [1597772703.322525671] [ros_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 1 rosgraph_msgs/Log to ROS 2 rcl_interfaces/msg/Log (showing msg only once per type)
[INFO] [1597772703.322748003] [ros_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 2 rcl_interfaces/msg/Log to ROS 1 rosgraph_msgs/Log (showing msg only once per type)
[INFO] [1597772703.322769446] [ros_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 2 rcl_interfaces/msg/Log to ROS 1 rosgraph_msgs/Log (showing msg only once per type)
created 1to2 bridge for topic '/rosout' with ROS 1 type 'rosgraph_msgs/Log' and ROS 2 type 'rcl_interfaces/msg/Log'
[INFO] [1597772703.927974308] [ros_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 1 rosgraph_msgs/Log to ROS 2 rcl_interfaces/msg/Log (showing msg only once per type)
^C[MrTurtle] root@turtlebot_0:~/ws/src/robotic_order_fulfillment_robotic_turtle/scripts$ removed 1to2 bridge for topic '/rosout'
```

Which consequently leads to the following (after sourcing setup.bash)

```
$ ros2 service list
/gazebo/pause_physics
/gazebo/reset_simulation
/gazebo/reset_world
/gazebo/unpause_physics
/master_discovery/refresh
/ros_bridge/describe_parameters
/ros_bridge/get_parameter_types
/ros_bridge/get_parameters
/ros_bridge/list_parameters
/ros_bridge/set_parameters
/ros_bridge/set_parameters_atomically
```

As you can see, **not all services are available in ROS2**. However, when I try to access the services that are availeble (e.g. `/gazebo/pause_physics` ) it does what is expected from it.

What should I do to see all the services available in ROS1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359849/ros2-foxy-ros1_bridge/) by [Lyubomyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/58058/lyubomyr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ros1_bridge` is implemented in C++ and therefore only supports bridging types it knows about at compile time. You can get a list of supported types by invoking: `ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --print-pairs`.

From the services which are not being bridged many (if not all?) seem to be of a service type defined in the `gazebo_msgs` package: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/bc4938fe5d08adfc853ad6d94bdde8b02e99dbe0/gazebo_msgs/srv

But `gazebo_msgs` is not an explicitly declared dependency of the `ros1_bridge` package: https://github.com/ros2-gbp/ros1_bridge-release/blob/b3a2e9657cd303fff26e219db471b0557600b519/debian/package.xml#L42-L67

As such you will need to build the `ros1_bridge` from source (with `gazebo_msgs` being present in the underlying ROS 1 and ROS 2 workspaces): https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge#building-the-bridge-from-source

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lyubomyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/58058/lyubomyr/) on 2020-08-19**:
It worked perfectly, thank you!